# Sending a message from Azure Service bus to AWS SQS

Tags: integration, azureservicebus

We have a requirement to implement Azure Service Bus as Integration point to various Applications (including apps hosted in AWS). Each application will have its own SQS. So the idea is to have  Azure Service Bus with Topics and Subscription filters to route messages to each SQS accordingly. However I am not sure as to how we can pick messages from a subscription filter and push the message to AWS SQS. I am not able to see any solution for this.

Answer (score 2):

These two are inherently two different messages services and you will either need to find a third party connector/bridge between the two or create your own. This would be a process that would be retrieving messages from one broker and forwarding it to another.

When it comes to a third party, there's an [example](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/router/bridge) that you could have a look at. NServiceBus has a community extension called Router. The router allows achieving exactly what you're looking for.

Disclaimer: I contribute and work on NServiceBus